# Issue with formatting my bootable USB Pendrive on Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, usb, usb-flash-drive

This question may seem kind of stupid but I'm genuinely not able to format my Pendrive. I used Etcher to make it bootable so that I could install Clear Linux. Now that I'm done with all of that I'm not able to format my Pendrive so that I can actually use it for normal stuff. It doesn't show up in This PC under Devices and Drives. When I went to the "clear and format hard disk partitions" program it's listed but when I right click it the format option is greyed out.

Some screenshots:

[Screenshot of Devices and Drives](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OMQDY.png)

[Screenshot of Program 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8ALwo.png)

[Screenshot of Program 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lQWhy.png)

[Screenshot of Program 3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1Hl4X.png)

I tried following this tutorial: https://www.instructables.com/id/How-to-reuse-revert-re-format-a-USB-flash-drive-fr/

But at step 6 I still wasn't able to see it under "Devices and Drives"

Note: my Pendrive is a "SanDisk Ultra USB 3.0" - 16GB

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you still have Linux, the easiest way is to use **GParted** (or possibly fdisk, or GNOME Disks, or KDE Partition Manager) to delete all unwanted partitions. Then you'll be able to create a new partition across the entire disk.

If all you have is Windows – run **`diskpart`**, then use the `list disk` and `select disk num` commands to choose your pendrive. (And use `detail disk` to make sure you got the right one.)

Then use `list partition` and `sel part num` to select the 1st partition (there should be only 1 listed) and delete it with `delete partition override`.

Comment: Worked as whished, Thanks!